# issue adding new parent and child rows using BindingListCollectionView wpf

Tags: wpf, master-detail

I have a parent child setup for projects (parent) and role allocations (child). The associated tables and relation has been setup in the `dataset` and I am reading and modifying the content using a `BindingListCollection` (which seems to be the closest thing to a `BindingSource` in wpf).

The issue however is that I am not able to add a parent and child row at the same time. If I create the parent row and commit to the database and then add the child row it works. Is there a way to add both the parent and child rows at the same time.

Code to add child row:

```
if (projectRoleAllocationView.CanAddNew)
{
    System.Data.DataRowView roleItem = (System.Data.DataRowView)availableRoleViewSource.View.CurrentItem;
    System.Data.DataRowView roleAllocationItem = (System.Data.DataRowView)roleAllocationViewSource.View.CurrentItem;
    System.Data.DataRowView projectItem = (System.Data.DataRowView)projectView.CurrentItem;

    System.Data.DataRowView projectRoleAllocationItem = (System.Data.DataRowView)projectRoleAllocationView.AddNew();
    projectRoleAllocationItem.Row["ID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
    projectRoleAllocationItem.Row["ProjectID"] = projectItem.Row["ID"];
    projectRoleAllocationItem.Row["RoleAllocationID"] = roleAllocationItem.Row["ID"];
    projectRoleAllocationItem.Row["RoleName"] = roleItem.Row["Name"];
    projectRoleAllocationItem.Row["ResourceName"] = roleAllocationItem.Row["Name"];
    projectRoleAllocationView.CommitNew();
    projectRoleAllocationView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to So; This is too much code and makes it difficult to answer the question. try to find out specific part of code causing the issue and just post that; or post a working solution reproducing the problem.

Comment: Hi. The most important aspect of the above code is the adding of the child row. I need to know whether this is correct: System.Data.DataRowView projectRoleAllocationItem = (System.Data.DataRowView)projectRoleAllocationView.AddNew();
   projectRoleAllocationView.CommitNew();
    projectRoleAllocationView.Refresh();

Comment: then you should edit the question and remove other unnecessary code.